# Chrome extension - interacting with pages that have JS errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first chrome extension and the extension I'm writing's purpose is to insert additional content into the webpage that you're on.

I've got a prototype working where I use a background job to execute some javascript which inserts the content onto the page. This works, the problem however is that some of the pages I visit have got javascript errors on them, and I think this is causing my javascript not to run properly...

Here's a couple of code snippets to explain how I've got things set up:

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "js/jquery/jquery.min.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "src/inject/container_injector.js" });
  });
});
```

container_injector.js

```
var body = $('body');
var bodyContainer = $('<div id="body_container"></div>').append(body);    
$('body').html('');
$('body').append(myContentContainer).append(bodyContainer);
```

I then have some jquery listeners for when you click on some of the content that gets added into the DOM, but they don't work sometimes if the page I'm on has javascript errors.

Does anyone know of a way to allow my javascript to run properly without being affected by existing javascript on the page?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "test.io",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "testing",
  "homepage_url": "http://test.io/",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "src/bg/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery/jquery.min.map"
  ],
  "options_page": "src/options/index.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
    "default_title": "test"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "cookies",
    "https://*.test.io/",
    "http://*.test.io/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/jquery/jquery.min.js",
        "src/inject/container_injector.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `manifest.json`?

Comment: Sure thing ;) just added.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've added `container_injector.js` anywhere in your `content_scripts` in the json.

Comment: Ahh.. yes you're right - strangely enough the javascript is working without having added it, but I'll add it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just added the container_injector to the content_scripts, and I still experience the same problems. It's not that my javascript doesn't run at all - it runs on a lot of sites, but the JS doesn't fire on sites like http://stuff.co.nz where there is a JS error coming through in the console...

Comment: What's the JS error? It's most likely the websites preventing potential security issues.

Comment: Another example is here on SO actually - there's an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined" which stops my inserted html from responding to the click event...

Comment: What line is the error pointing to? And can you upload the JS on and around that line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45674/discussion-between-louis-sayers-and-mjkaufer)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error was due to temporarily removing the body html - which meant that the host page's javascript could not find javascript references.

I solved this by not removing the body's html, but instead prepending my container on the body element like so:

```
$('body').prepend(myContentContainer);
```

Thanks to @mjkaufer for his suggestion of prepending the container in the body! I did have to play with negative margins a bit to achieve the effect I was after, but I believe that it's a workable solution for now :)